# array destructuring mongoose create

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

is there any other way to insert a data into mongoose without using array desctructuring
i have some code below, it doesnt work, also it doesnt insert correctly into database

```
const data = req.file.originalname.split('.')[0].split('_');
if (data.length < 5) throw new Error('Invalid file name');

const content = await fs.readFile(req.file.path, 'utf8');
await orders.create({ data, content });
```

i can make this work by using this code by using array desctructuring like below, what i want to know is there any way without using desctructuring, and just using variable data like my code above

```
const data = req.file.originalname.split('.')[0].split('_');
if (data.length < 5) throw new Error('Invalid file name');

// const [no_telp, type, timespan, name, unique_code] = data;
const content = await fs.readFile(req.file.path, 'utf8');
await orders.create({ no_telp, type, timespan, name, unique code, content });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is not array destructuring. Array destructuring means pulling data out of array. An example array destructuring could be `const listCopy = [...list]` or `const listAdded = [...list, 12, 48]`. If you mean this part `create({ no_telp, type, timespan, name, unique code, content });` you are providing neessary data into create method. You can create an abject beforehand and just send pass it to create method. `const userData = { no_telp, type, timespan, name, unique code, content }; await orders.create(userData);`
Additionally, what you are trying to save is a stringified data. After reading a file with `fs.readFile()` you must parse it to manipulate and save in database correctly. Try this:

```
const stringData = await fs.readFile(req.file.path, 'utf8');
const content = JSON.parse(stringData)
console.log(content) // see the data
const userData = {no_telp, type, timespan, name, unique code, content};
await orders.create(userData);
```

Comment: i dont mean it like that, what i want to do not about content, but like code below
const [no_telp, type, timespan, name, unique_code] = data;
i can use it like this like my code, is there any ways beside using desctructuring array like this so i can use it like this
await orders.create({ data, content });